# How to create XML format file programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Mytrip>
    <start_time>06/06/2013 09:00:00 AM</start_time>
    <end_time>06/06/2013 09:30:00 AM</end_time>      
    <start_address> 12 NGO, Roseville, Mp</start_address> 
    <start_gps>+40.689060,-74.044636</start_gps>
    <end_address>8 STE stree, Roseville, MP</end_address>
    <end_gps>+42.689060, -72.044636</end_gps>
    <duration>00:00:00:00</duration>
    <label>Roseville Trip</label>
    <route>
        <point>
            <gps>+40.689060,-74.044636</gps>
            <speed>1.2 Miles/Hr</speed>
        </point>
        <point>
            <gps>+41.689060,-74.044636</gps>
            <speed>5.0 Miles/Hr</speed>
        </point>
   </route>
</Mytrip>
```

i want create XML file above format.. in this -point- can be multiple means i getting the data from my database..

Comment: Is this for sending to some remote server? Any chance that can support JSON, instead? It's trivial to encode/decode JSON in iOS using built in classes. XML isn't hard, but takes a little more work (no built in XML encoder so you have to write your own or use third party routine; XML parsing (which you're admittedly not doing here, but still) takes a little more work than JSON parsing does). If you have to use XML, I'm sure the answers below will help.

Answer (score 3):

As many suggested you can do it with third party libraries. A sample on how you can do it with GDataXML.

Start by creating custom objects suitable to hold the data. Identify the nodes. Here there are two nodes

1. Trip
2. Point

Create Model classes for them. For sake of simplicity I have made all of them as string. Ideally it would be better to include the times as `NSDate` and coordinates as `CLLocation` and duration in seconds.

```
@interface Trip : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *label;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *start_address;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *end_address;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *start_time;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *end_time;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *start_gps;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *end_gps;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *duration;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *points;

- (GDataXMLElement *)XMLNode;
- (NSString *)XMLString;
```

.m file

```
@implementation Trip

- (GDataXMLElement *)XMLNode{

    GDataXMLElement *tripNode = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"Mytrip"];

    GDataXMLElement *startTimeElement = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"start_time" stringValue:self.start_time];
    [tripNode addChild:startTimeElement];
    GDataXMLElement *endTimeElement = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"end_time" stringValue:self.end_time];
    [tripNode addChild:endTimeElement];

    GDataXMLElement *startAddressElement = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"start_address" stringValue:self.start_address];
    [tripNode addChild:startAddressElement];
    GDataXMLElement *endAddressElement = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"end_address" stringValue:self.end_address];
    [tripNode addChild:endAddressElement];

    GDataXMLElement *startGpsElement = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"start_gps" stringValue:self.start_gps];
    [tripNode addChild:startGpsElement];
    GDataXMLElement *endGpsElement = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"end_gps" stringValue:self.end_gps];
    [tripNode addChild:endGpsElement];

    GDataXMLElement *durationElement = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"duration" stringValue:self.duration];
    [tripNode addChild:durationElement];

    GDataXMLElement *labelElement = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"label" stringValue:self.label];
    [tripNode addChild:labelElement];

    GDataXMLElement *routeNode = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"route"];

    for (RoutePoint *point in self.points) {
        GDataXMLElement *pointNode = [point XMLNode];
        [routeNode addChild:pointNode];
    }

    [tripNode addChild:routeNode];

    return tripNode;
}

- (NSString *)XMLString{
    return [[self XMLNode] XMLString];
}
```

The same for Route point

```
@interface RoutePoint : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *gps;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *speed;

- (GDataXMLElement *)XMLNode;
- (NSString *)XMLString;
```

.m file

```
@implementation RoutePoint

- (GDataXMLElement *)XMLNode{

    GDataXMLElement *pointNode = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"point"];

    GDataXMLElement *gpsElement = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"gps" stringValue:self.gps];
    GDataXMLElement *speedElement = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"speed" stringValue:self.speed];

    [pointNode addChild:gpsElement];
    [pointNode addChild:speedElement];

    return pointNode;
}

- (NSString *)XMLString{
    return [[self XMLNode] XMLString];
}
```

Create an instance of Trip populate the values

```
Trip *trip = [Trip new];

trip.start_time = @"06/06/2013 09:00:00 AM";
trip.end_time = @"06/06/2013 09:30:00 AM";

trip.start_address = @"12 NGO, Roseville, Mp";
trip.end_address = @"8 STE stree, Roseville, MP";

trip.start_gps = @"+40.689060,-74.044636";
trip.end_gps = @"+42.689060, -72.044636";

trip.duration = @"00:00:00:00";
trip.label = @"Roseville Trip";

RoutePoint *point = [RoutePoint new];
point.gps = @"+40.689060,-74.044636";
point.speed = @"1.2 Miles/Hr";

trip.points = @[point];

NSLog(@"%@",[trip XMLString]);
```

Answer (score -3):

I thought about it, some time )) There are some XMLWriter classes, to create XML.
But I haven't enough time to understand how they work. Any way, XML is just a string, which you convert into data. In that case i created it by myself ))

```
NSMutableString *XMLString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[XMLString appendString:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?> \n"];
[XMLString appendString:@"<scene> \n"];
//... etc..
```

You can say that it's bad example, but it works for me )